# href# moves the scroll position

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

Hi when you click the a link i want it to toggle the 'vartalo' without page going scrolling to the top, i want 'A' to be link like that but dont want it to scroll the page up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >  
<html>    
<style>    
#oikea{
position:absolute; 
top:800px;  
}    

.paneelinvartalo{   
border:1px solid black;   
background-color:lightblue;   
margin-top:5px;    
padding:15px;    
height:200px;   
width:200px;   
}

</style>  
<body>    
<div id="panel1" class="paneelinvartalo">vartalo    
</div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   
</script>

<script>   
$(function(){    
   $('.nappulat').click(function(){   
   $('#panel1').toggle(200);            
   });  
   });

</script> 
<div id="oikea" >   
<a class="nappulat" href="#" rel="">A< /a>     
</div>    
</body>      
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the default action of the link that takes you to to the top of the page. The URL `#` is the empty bookmark, which is the same thing as linking to a named bookmark anchor placed at the top of the page.

Use the `preventDefault` method to stop the default action of the link:

```
$('.nappulat').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#panel1').toggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){    
    $('.nappulat').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#panel1').toggle(200);
    });
});
```